# Execution error--Permission denied

Tags: permissions

I'm new to Ubuntu OS (have installed 14.04.2)
I was trying to install Oracle software, and I got the "Permission denied" error. And I have already changed the permission of the file using "chmod 777"
I also tried as root user, but even that was in vain.

```
oracle@sysadmin-Lenovo-B460e:~$ pwd
/home/oracle
oracle@sysadmin-Lenovo-B460e:~$ ls -ltr
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 17 17:57 Videos
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 17 17:57 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 17 17:57 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 17 17:57 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 17 17:57 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 17 17:57 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 17 17:57 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 3 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 17 17:59 Desktop
oracle@sysadmin-Lenovo-B460e:~$ cd Desktop
oracle@sysadmin-Lenovo-B460e:~/Desktop$ ls -ltr
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 3 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 17 12:42 linux_11gR2_database
oracle@sysadmin-Lenovo-B460e:~/Desktop$ cd linux_11gR2_database
oracle@sysadmin-Lenovo-B460e:~/Desktop/linux_11gR2_database$ ls -ltr
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 8 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 12 17:32 database
oracle@sysadmin-Lenovo-B460e:~/Desktop/linux_11gR2_database$ cd database
oracle@sysadmin-Lenovo-B460e:~/Desktop/linux_11gR2_database/database$ ls -ltr
total 40
-rwxrwxrwx  1 oracle oinstall 4352 Aug 13  2009 runInstaller
-rw-------  1 oracle oinstall 5400 Aug 17  2009 welcome.html
drwxrwxrwx 12 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 12 17:29 doc
drwxrwxrwx  4 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 12 17:30 install
drwxrwxrwx  2 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 12 17:30 response
drwxrwxrwx  2 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 12 17:30 rpm
drwxrwxrwx  2 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 12 17:30 sshsetup
drwxrwxrwx 14 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 12 17:32 stage
oracle@sysadmin-Lenovo-B460e:~/Desktop/linux_11gR2_database/database$ sh runInstaller
runInstaller: 137: runInstaller: /home/oracle/Desktop/linux_11gR2_database/database/install/.oui: Permission denied
oracle@sysadmin-Lenovo-B460e:~/Desktop/linux_11gR2_database/database$ sudo su root
[sudo] password for oracle: 
root@sysadmin-Lenovo-B460e:/home/oracle/Desktop/linux_11gR2_database/database# sh runInstaller
runInstaller: 137: runInstaller: /home/oracle/Desktop/linux_11gR2_database/database/install/.oui: Permission denied
root@sysadmin-Lenovo-B460e:/home/oracle/Desktop/linux_11gR2_database/database#
```

Any suggestion/help would be much helpful to me.

Thanks a lot..

Comment: Are you trying to install 32-bit (x86) software on a 64-bit (x86-64) platform, by any chance?

Comment: Nope. The software and the platform both are 32-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check permissions of `.oui` file located at `/home/oracle/Desktop/linux_11gR2_database/database/install/.oui`.
 Please give read,write, execution permissions to it.

```
chmod 777 -R /home/oracle/Desktop/linux_11gR2_database/database/
```

Please check permission of `oraInst.loc` located at `/etc/oraInst.loc`
Permissions should be

```
-rw-r--r-- root root /etc/oraInst.loc
```

Set this permission by executed as a root user

```
chmod 755 oraInst.loc
```